# Converting Names in a list to a number to be referenced in OSC string

Tags: applescript

I have a drop down list that when the answer is selected I need to turn that answer into a number that is added onto a OSC string

If I change the & theRoomID to just theRoom the OSC message is correct as text but not as a number value.

I keep getting the error The Variable theRoomID is not defined.

AppleScript is as follows:

```
set theRoomChoices to {"Off", "Modern Small", "Classic Small", "Modern Medium", "Classic Medium", "Modern         Large", "Classic Large", "Modern Medium 2", "Theatre", "Cathederal"}
set theRoom to choose from list theRoomChoices with prompt "Choose your En Space Room:" default items {"Off"}

if theRoom = "Off" then set theRoomID to "0"
if theRoom = "Modern Small" then set theRoomID to "1"
if theRoom = "Classic Small" then set theRoomID to "2"

tell application id "com.figure53.QLab.4"

tell front workspace
    make type "Network"
    set theNewCue to last item of (selected as list)
    
    set osc message type of theNewCue to custom
    set patch of theNewCue to 4
    set q name of theNewCue to "EN Space Room Set to " & theRoom
    set q color of theNewCue to "Orange"
    set the q number of theNewCue to ""
    set the custom message of theNewCue to "/dbaudio1/matrixsettings/reverbroomid " & theRoomID
end tell

end tell
```

Comment: Note that the result from `choose from list` will be a _list_ (or `false` for "Cancel").